# LookAt() работает наоборот

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу сделать игру, где враг будет меня преследовать, и при этом он должен смотреть в мою сторону. Но когда я пытаюсь посмотреть врагу в лицо, он от меня отворачивается, когда бегает, стоит боком. Что делать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _player; //переменная для игрока
    public Transform _playerRotation; //ещё одна переменная для игрока(чтобы сохранить повороты
    public float _speed; //скорость врага

    void Update()
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, new Vector3(_good.transform.position.x, 0, _good.transform.position.z), _speed); //передвижение врага за игроком

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1.999444f, transform.position.z); //чтобы враг не проваливался под пол

         transform.LookAt(_playerRotation.position); //чтобы враг смотрел на главного героя


    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518199/373567 чем этот вопрос отличается от того что вы удалили? Если никто не ответил, значит с вопросом что-то не так, верно?